# Movie where guy pilots ship to his death screaming "IT'S SO BEAUTIFUL!"?

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

All I can remember is that he had to pilot the ship through some supernova or other anomaly to save the other passenger.

Comment: "It's so beautiful" were the first words spoken in space (in Russian) by Gagarin. I wonder if Stephen King was referencing that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I believe you are thinking of Stephen King's [The Langoliers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112040/) (2-part TV miniseries).  The scene in question is near the end when Nick Hopewell draws the short straw and must remain awake to pilot the aircraft back through the time rift.  As discovered during the initial passage through the rift, anyone on board the plane who is awake will vanish from existence (and assume died).

In this case it was actually several (6 or so, I think) passengers and a regular, current era passenger jet, plus the true pilot of the plane.  His final words before blinking from existence were "It's so beautiful" referring to the colored lights of the rift.

[image: Langoliers rift]

Comment: @Richard - thanks for adding the pic.  Provides a much better explaination of the 'colored lights of the rift'

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of "Sunshine" from 2007, starring Cillian Murphy. I remember that scene being towards the end.

Answer (score -2):

The independent day acted by Will Smith? There was a father who used to be prisoned by aliens decided to crash the alien spaceship with his plane. He was a pilot.

Comment: Nope. The character you're referring to is Russell Casse, whose last words as he collides with the alien ship are "Hello boys, I'm back!" I think you're confusing his line with Tiffany's last words at the rooftop party in LA, when she says "it's so pretty".